# Create GIF works on iOS7, breaks on iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, gif

I have some rather straightforward code that creates a GIF image from a set of UIImages.
It works perfectly fine on iOS7. On iOS8 there is a file created, but it is somehow broken (doesn't work on device or when downloaded to desktop). Here is the example code:

```
...

float frameTime = (1/(fps * speed));

NSString *fileOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%ld", NSTemporaryDirectory(), time(NULL)];

CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileOutput],kUTTypeGIF,[images count],NULL);

NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:frameTime] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime],(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary,kCFBooleanFalse,kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha,[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0],kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality, nil];

NSMutableDictionary *gifProps = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[gifProps setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap];
[gifProps setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount];
[gifProps setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyHasAlpha];
[gifProps setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality];

NSDictionary *gifProperties = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:gifProps forKey:(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary ];

for (int i = 0; i<[images count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, im.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
        im = nil;
    }
}

CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);

...
```

There are no warning messages and no erros on execution.
What could be causing the problem?

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing on iOS 8.1.3, with the workaround to set kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap to true. Memory is much larger, though, and my use case in an app extension makes it impossible to use without getting watchdogged. Let us know if you have any updates.

Comment: The memory use may be much larger due to the color map not actually being set correctly. A red herring. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple confirms this is an iOS8 bug, submitted (18512475).

Comment: Any update from apple whether this bug will be fixed or if there is a workaround.

Comment: I've run into the same issue. Strangely I had no problems on iPhones (tested 5, 5C, 6, 6 Plus), but iPad (Air, mini 2) fail to create a GIF with the same settings.

My workaround for this is to set kCGImagePropertyGIFHasGlobalColorMap to YES. However this uses significantly more heap memory (peak memory is 115 MB vs. 5 MB for 20 frames each with a size of 640x480).

I also quickly tried to use ANGif library which however takes forever and uses about the same memory. To be fair I've not tried optimizing it (yet).

Comment: is any update from apple..  ?
what is `18512475`?
I have searched with above number. but i could not find anything..

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the GIF properties *before* adding the images. There is a color mapping algorithm, and it's expecting to be able to look at the images in order to create the color map correctly.

```
NSDictionary *gifProperties = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:gifProps forKey:(NSString*) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary ];

CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);


for (int i = 0; i<[images count]; i++)
{
    UIImage *im = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    @autoreleasepool
    {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, im.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
        im = nil;
    }
}

CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);
```